# Is SSLSocket communication secure using the attached code?

Tags: java, ssl, java-io, sslstream, sslsocketfactory

I developed a Chat Server and client using `Sockets` and everything has been fine until I read somewhere online that ordinary `Socket` communication is vulnerable to attacks. After googling a while, I came across [this page](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/MSC00-J.+Use+SSLSocket+rather+than+Socket+for+secure+data+exchange) that showed a sample `SSLServerSocket` and `SSLSocket` implementation (code below).

I will like to know if the communication between my server and client is secure if I follow steps in the below code.

**Server Code**

```
class EchoServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = null;
    try {
      SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketFactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
      sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(9999);
      SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sslSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sslSocket.getInputStream()));
      String inputLine;
      while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        out.println(inputLine);
      }
    } finally {
      if (sslServerSocket != null) {
        try {
          sslServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException x) {
          // handle error
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Client Code**

```
class EchoClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SSLSocket sslSocket = null;
    try {
      SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
      sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket("localhost", 9999);
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sslSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sslSocket.getInputStream()));
      BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      String userInput;
      while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(userInput);
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
      }
    } finally {
      if (sslSocket != null) {
        try {
          sslSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException x) {
          // handle error
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review.

Comment: @AbidingCitizen - Following aliteralmind, you might try here: [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I disagree. The OP is asking about properties of the existing code, not whether it can be coded better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the peer certificate via a HandshakeCompletionListener or the SSLSession to verify that you're talking to the host you think you're talking to. Other than that your code is OK from the security point of view.

However you should also be aware that you shouldn't use PrintWriter over a network, as it swallows exceptions.

Comment: Thanks once again for coming to my rescue.

Comment: Another way to check the hostname (not available before Java 7) is to use [setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("HTTPS")](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17979954/372643).

Comment: @Bruno Thanks, will take note of that