# SSLContext with hostname verification

Tags: java, security, ssl

While testing my client-server distributed system, I was surprised at first to learn that the default JSSE implementation of TLS doesn't do hostname verification. I tried the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972658/sslsocket-ignores-domain-mismatch/17979954#17979954) question, but my use case is a bit different. I use RabbitMQ's connection factory, which abstracts the SSLSocket's construction. I just provide the connection factory with an SSLContext. I did find a lot about HTTPS and even some other protocols, but not something general that can always be used, even with custom protocols.

There's not really much to be found about creating a domain-verifying SSLContext though, except for using the `X509ExtendedTrustManager`. While debugging, I can see that

```
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
tmf.init((KeyStore) null);
tmf.getTrustManagers();
```

returns one `TrustManager`, a `X509TrustManagerImpl`, which according to [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/sun/security/ssl/X509TrustManagerImpl.java) page extends `X509ExtendedTrustManager`. This one does not, however, reject a faulty certificate (and by 'faulty' I mean that the certificate does not match the server's hostname).

So I then resorted to writing my own `X509ExtendedTrustManager`, which delegates to the trust managers from my `TrustManagerFactory`:

```
final TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
X509ExtendedTrustManager x509ExtendedTrustManager = new X509ExtendedTrustManager() {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) throws CertificateException {
        checkClientTrusted(x509Certificates, s);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) throws CertificateException {
        checkServerTrusted(x509Certificates, s);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) throws CertificateException {
        checkClientTrusted(x509Certificates, s);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) throws CertificateException {
        checkServerTrusted(x509Certificates, s);
    }

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
        for (TrustManager trustManager : trustManagers)
            ((X509TrustManager)trustManager).checkClientTrusted(x509Certificates, s);
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
        for (TrustManager trustManager : trustManagers)
            ((X509TrustManager)trustManager).checkServerTrusted(x509Certificates, s);

        for (X509Certificate x509Certificate : x509Certificates) {
            Collection<List<?>> alternativeNameCollection = x509Certificate.getSubjectAlternativeNames();
            if (alternativeNameCollection != null) {
                for (List alternativeNames : alternativeNameCollection) {
                    if (alternativeNames.get(1).equals(host))
                        return;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new CertificateException("Certificate hostname and requested hostname don't match");
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
};
```

This does finally work. But I cannot believe there wouldn't be a cleaner way to do this. Basically what I'm looking for is something standard, because I think what I'm doing is pretty standard too. I read about `HostnameVerifier` but is there a way to use it with SSLContext without using HTTPS? Is there a hostname-verifying implementation of `X509ExtendedTrustManager` somewhere? I'm sure I'm reinventing things that have already been written.

**EDIT:** [this](https://gist.github.com/jfwilson/709b74000a79eb52177b) is a good, working example. Still custom code though.

**EDIT 2:** The problem still remains with RabbitMQ, because RabbitMQ resolves the DNS and passes the IP address to the verifier, which of course always fails. So the `X509ExtendedTrustManager` still seems the way to go.

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest this could be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17972658/372643) (i.e. you do actually get something out of the box in the JSSE, starting with Java 7). I'm not sure how your RabbitMQ library implements hostname verification, but if it doesn't, it's a bug there.

Comment: I agree that the questions are very similar, they are both about hostname verification. The difference IMO is that that question and its answers are all about HTTPS. I'm looking for a general solution, basically to add a hostname verification feature to any protocol and I just find it dangerous and unmaintainable to write code like this myself (which, for now, is how I've solved it). I would rather rely on a library that has been implemented by a team with more knowledge on this subject.

Comment: @delucasvb see https://tersesystems.com/2014/03/23/fixing-hostname-verification/ for more on this

Comment: I use Netty for network comm. It does hostname verification by default, including for raw TLS sockets.

Answer (score -1):

Hostname verification isn't part of SSL. It is part of HTTPS. You're investigating the wrong layer and the wrong APIs. You should be looking into `HttpURLConnection` and `HostnameVerifier`.

Comment: I'm using other protocols than HTTPS, some of which are custom.

Comment: That doesn't change my answer in any way.

Comment: I edited my question. I tried working with a hostname verifier, but this doesn't always work because it doesn't always receive a hostname. Some libraries or frameworks (like RabbitMQ) will send it an IP address.

Comment: That doesn't change my answer in any way either.

Comment: @EJP https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509ExtendedTrustManager.html You are right that hostname verification is done at HTTPS not at SSL/TLS layer but the above class does exist for doing both certificate chain checks and hostname verification with one API call. The doc says "This class allows for the checking to be done during a single call to this class."

Comment: Hostname verification is not "part of HTTPS." It has nothing to with HTTP. It's an optional step that any TLS client can do, but required for HTTP-over-TLS.

Comment: There are quite a view protocols like SMTP, IMAP, ... which are not HTTP but use SSL/TLS. Based of what you wrote those protocols should not have/perform host name verification - which is nonsense. See [RFC6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125)